# How to set app icon and splash screen for IOS using visual studio tools for apache cordova?

Tags: ios, visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2013

I am building an Apache Cordova app using Visual Studio 2013 with the tools for Apache Cordova extension.
I cannot change the icon that appears in the Apple Store or in iTunesConnect.
I am able to change the icon for android and google play store however.
I have changed the files in res/screens/ios and res/icons/ios accordingly, but it doesn't seem to be updating when I create a new IPA and upload it.
This is the icon I am getting at the moment and this image does not exist anywhere in my project directory structure.

[image: Default apache icon]

Comment: Are your ios icons referenced in your config.xml? The icon you get is the default icon for a cordova app.

Comment: how do i have to reference my icons in the config.xml?
I know it's the default icon, even though i can't find that icon in my folders anymore as I have replaced it.

Comment: Check the cordova docs : http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/config_ref_images.md.html that's what works for me.

Comment: yes, that fixed it. But the paths are a bit different for Visual Studio tools for apache.

Comment: If you add your comment as an answer i will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you need to set image in below locations. There will be default folder created with default cordova logos and splashscreen.
[image]

Comment: I **did** do this already. But the icon does not show up on IOS

Comment: Clean build the project again. It must be picking up files from your cache.

Answer (score 4):

Please notice that the value of the "src" attribute is relative **to the project directory** and **not to the www** directory. You **can rename the source image** whatever you like. The internal name in the app are determined by Cordova.

```
<platform name="ios">
    <!-- iOS 8.0+ -->
    <!-- iPhone 6 Plus  -->
    <icon src="res/ios/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" height="180" />
    <!-- other icons -->
 </platform>
```

Comment: this made my day bro.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

note icons must match the size (height and width).